# Variable Names That are Created on runtime

Tags: vb.net, variables, automation

Is there  a way in VB to create variables that are created on run time with that are automatically named

```
For y As Integer = 0 To 100
        Dim Varible{y} as integer
Next
```

Comment: Your example looks like it could be satisfied by an array `Dim Variable(100) As Integer` defines an array of 101 integers that can be referenced as Variable(0), Variable(1), ..... Variable(100).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create the name of a variable at runtime, but you can use a collection of variables with a specified key (name) for each element, or a class with a single public variable or property plus a name property.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use an array?

```
Dim Variable(100) As Integer
```